# Transform 5 2xAA battery power supplies TO 1 power supply

Tags: led-strip

I bought some LED stripes here : https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Neon-LED-Light-Glowing-ELWire-Strip-Tube-Car-Party-Decoration-1M-Lemon-Green-3-Modes-Waterproof/32797496356.html

They are all powered by two AA batteries (1,5V).

I would like to wired them all together and power them by a single USB battery like this one : https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Universal-5V-9V-12V-6-x-18650-Dual-USB-Portable-External-Power-Bank-Battery-Charger-Box/32242946314.html

I'm a little bit afraid by voltage and amp risks, to be sure it will work perfectly.

If I did my research correctly, 1 stripe needs 3V to work correctly.
Then to wire 5 of them I'll need 15V right ?

I'm a little bit lost but I don't want to wear 5 to 10 power supplies with... 10 to 20 batteries !! (I want to create a LED outfit)

Thanks a lot for your advices !

Comment: You can put them in parallel. You still need 3V but 5 times more current. Or any combination you like

Comment: Then you mean connecting all + together and all - together ?
Then I'll have one + and one -, that I will connect to a regular connector and plug to my external battery ?

Comment: You can try putting two strips in series (6V) and see if you can power them with your 5V supply. If this works, then you can put 3 of those arrangements in parallel, for a total of 6 strips

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems.

1. Those are not led, they are EL wire with an inverter.
2. That battery pack expects Lithium cells, of the 18650 type, not AA alkaline or nimh or nicd. (I don't know if you are aware).
3. They will pull what they need so do not worry about having a power source with higher capacity or current sourcing ability.
4. You can use a voltage regulator like a buck or step down regulator to bring any of the voltages down to the 3V the inverters expect.

Comment: The advertisement says they run on 2xAA cells.

Comment: @Simon the initial title was not clear on that

Comment: @Passerby yes it needs AA cells (I'm vaping then it's sad because I have a lot of 18650 batteries :p)
But yes it's not LED but EL wire ! 

Then you say I can't directly connect them to the battery and need to keep the inverter for each wire ?